# matching the elements of list in data frame and calculate their mean in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have a list that has a length equal to the number of columns in a data frame.

The example is as following

```
set.seed(123)
list1 <- list(a = c("cat", "dog", "duck", "mice"), b = 
            c("cat", "dog"), c = c("duck", "dog"))

df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10), 
             row.names = c("cat", "dog", "duck", "mice",
                           "elephant","monkey", "lion",
                           "goat", "cow", "sheep"))
```

Then the elements of each `list1` name should match the row names in the `df` for each column and calculate their mean. For example:

The elements of `list$a` are:

```
`[1] "cat"  "dog"  "duck" "mice"`
```

The Above elements should match the row names for column `a` and calculate the mean i.e `.20964`.

I want to do this for all columns in the data frame by using a vectorize operations in `R` where the output is list of mean for all columns in `df`.

I have looked for similar question on SO but cant find any. Please excuse me if I've overlooked.

**EDIT**

Please excuse if conveyed I it wrong but the output I want should be like:

```
a          b         c
1 0.2096409 -0.3953266 0.6642654
```

where `b` is the mean of `df$b` that matches `list1$b` elements with the row names of `df`and so forth.

Comment: The mean of column a for list1$a isn't 0.17 but 0.61. Or I didn't understand you.

Comment: @Haboryme  OP created the dataset without a `set.seed`.  So whatever values you get would be different from others.

Comment: @Akrun ty for pointing that out. I'm not bright.

Comment: Please see the changes in the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We loop through the 'list1', subset the rows of 'df' based on the rownames in the `list` elements and get the `colMeans`

```
lapply(list1, function(nm) colMeans(df[nm,], na.rm=TRUE))
#$a
     a          b          c 
# 0.2096409  0.5238374 -0.7601736 

#$b
#        a          b          c  
#-0.3953266  0.7919478 -0.6428993 

#$c
#        a          b          c 
# 0.6642654  0.3802926 -0.6219897
```

Comment: thank you for pointing it out. I have added a set.seed to the post and edited the required output.

Comment: @AzamYahya  If you apply the codde, it is what I get

Comment: The output I am seeking is the mean of each column in `df`.

Comment: @AzamYahya  It is what the `colMeans` does after subsetting the rows

Comment: your output is different from mines. please see the EDIT in the post.

Comment: @AzamYahya  If you use `sapply(list1, function(nm) colMeans(df[nm,], na.rm=TRUE))` you get similar output

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
lapply(list1, function(l) sapply(df[l, ], mean))
```

Comment: Maybe the op never heard of seeds?

Comment: Thanks for the post but the output I require is different. Please see the edited post.